# highcharts crosshairs wont work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

been trying to enable crosshairs on highcharts.... on jsfindle the example works fine, but when i put it into my web page it just won't work, can you please check the code?
Thanks

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
     renderTo: 'chartcontainer'
  },

  tooltip: {
      crosshairs: [true,true],
      shared: true,
      enabled: true
  },

  plotOptions: {
      series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },

  series: [{
      data: [[3809.6, 1.1], [3823.26, 1.27], [3836.91, 1.4], [3850.57, 1.48], [3864.22,        1.56], [3877.88, 1.71], [3891.53, 1.92], [3905.19, 2.07], [3918.84, 2.09], [3932.49, 2.02], [3946.15, 1.99], [3959.8, 2.04], [3973.46, 2.16], [3987.11, 2.29], [4000.77, 2.38], [4014.42, 2.41], [4028.08, 2.39], [4041.73, 2.35], [4055.38, 2.26], [4069.04, 2.14], [4082.69, 2.06], [4096.35, 2.04], [4110, 2.1], [4123.66, 2.19], [4137.31, 2.26], [4150.97, 2.28], [4164.62, 2.29], [4178.28, 2.28], [4191.93, 2.27], [4205.58, 2.25], [4219.24, 2.23], [4232.89, 2.2], [4246.55, 2.18], [4260.2, 2.16], [4273.86, 2.13], [4287.51, 2.09], [4301.17, 2.02], [4314.82, 1.94], [4328.47, 1.89], [4342.13, 1.86], [4355.78, 1.88], [4369.44, 1.91], [4383.09, 1.94], [4396.75, 1.94], [4410.4, 1.94], [4424.06, 1.93], [4437.71, 1.91], [4451.37, 1.9], [4465.02, 1.88], [4478.67, 1.87], [4492.33, 1.85], [4505.98, 1.83], [4519.64, 1.82], [4533.29, 1.8], [4546.95, 1.79], [4560.6, 1.77], [4574.26, 1.75], [4587.91, 1.74], [4601.56, 1.73], [4615.22, 1.71], [4628.87, 1.7], [4642.53, 1.69], [4656.18, 1.67], [4669.84, 1.66], [4683.49, 1.65], [4697.15, 1.63], [4710.8, 1.62], [4724.46, 1.61], [4738.11, 1.59], [4751.76, 1.58], [4765.42, 1.56], [4779.07, 1.54], [4792.73, 1.52], [4806.38, 1.49], [4820.04, 1.46], [4833.69, 1.43], [4847.35, 1.4], [4861, 1.38], [4874.65, 1.37], [4888.31, 1.38], [4901.96, 1.38], [4915.62, 1.38], [4929.27, 1.38], [4942.93, 1.38], [4956.58, 1.37], [4970.24, 1.36], [4983.89, 1.35], [4997.54, 1.34], [5011.2, 1.33], [5024.85, 1.32], [5038.51, 1.31], [5052.16, 1.3], [5065.82, 1.3], [5079.47, 1.29], [5093.13, 1.28], [5106.78, 1.27], [5120.44, 1.26], [5134.09, 1.25], [5147.74, 1.24], [5161.4, 1.23], [5175.05, 1.21], [5188.71, 1.2], [5202.36, 1.19], [5216.02, 1.18], [5229.67, 1.18], [5243.33, 1.17], [5256.98, 1.16], [5270.63, 1.15], [5284.29, 1.15], [5297.94, 1.14], [5311.6, 1.13], [5325.25, 1.12], [5338.91, 1.11], [5352.56, 1.11], [5366.22, 1.1], [5379.87, 1.09], [5393.53, 1.08], [5407.18, 1.07], [5420.83, 1.06], [5434.49, 1.05], [5448.14, 1.04], [5461.8, 1.03], [5475.45, 1.03], [5489.11, 1.02], [5502.76, 1.01], [5516.42, 1], [5530.07, 1], [5543.72, 0.99], [5557.38, 0.98], [5571.03, 0.98], [5584.69, 0.97], [5598.34, 0.97], [5612, 0.96], [5625.65, 0.95], [5639.31, 0.95], [5652.96, 0.94], [5666.62, 0.93], [5680.27, 0.93], [5693.92, 0.92], [5707.58, 0.91], [5721.23, 0.91], [5734.89, 0.9], [5748.54, 0.89], [5762.2, 0.89], [5775.85, 0.88], [5789.51, 0.88], [5803.16, 0.87], [5816.81, 0.87], [5830.47, 0.86], [5844.12, 0.85], [5857.78, 0.85], [5871.43, 0.84], [5885.09, 0.84], [5898.74, 0.83], [5912.4, 0.83], [5926.05, 0.82], [5939.71, 0.82], [5953.36, 0.81], [5967.01, 0.81], [5980.67, 0.8], [5994.32, 0.8], [6007.98, 0.8], [6021.63, 0.79], [6035.29, 0.79], [6048.94, 0.79], [6062.6, 0.78], [6076.25, 0.78], [6089.9, 0.77], [6103.56, 0.77], [6117.21, 0.76], [6130.87, 0.76], [6144.52, 0.75], [6158.18, 0.75], [6171.83, 0.75], [6185.49, 0.74], [6199.14, 0.74], [6212.79, 0.73], [6226.45, 0.73], [6240.1, 0.72], [6253.76, 0.72], [6267.41, 0.72], [6281.07, 0.72], [6294.72, 0.71], [6308.38, 0.71], [6322.03, 0.71], [6335.69, 0.7], [6349.34, 0.7], [6362.99, 0.7], [6376.65, 0.7], [6390.3, 0.69], [6403.96, 0.69], [6417.61, 0.68], [6431.27, 0.68], [6444.92, 0.67], [6458.58, 0.67], [6472.23, 0.66], [6485.88, 0.65], [6499.54, 0.64], [6513.19, 0.63], [6526.85, 0.62], [6540.5, 0.62], [6554.16, 0.61], [6567.81, 0.61], [6581.47, 0.61], [6595.12, 0.6], [6608.78, 0.61], [6622.43, 0.61], [6636.08, 0.61], [6649.74, 0.61], [6663.39, 0.62], [6677.05, 0.62], [6690.7, 0.62], [6704.36, 0.62], [6718.01, 0.62], [6731.67, 0.61], [6745.32, 0.61], [6758.97, 0.61], [6772.63, 0.6], [6786.28, 0.6], [6799.94, 0.59], [6813.59, 0.58], [6827.25, 0.57], [6840.9, 0.57], [6854.56, 0.56], [6868.21, 0.56], [6881.87, 0.55], [6895.52, 0.54], [6909.17, 0.54], [6922.83, 0.53], [6936.48, 0.53], [6950.14, 0.53], [6963.79, 0.54], [6977.45, 0.54], [6991.1, 0.54], [7004.76, 0.54], [7018.41, 0.54], [7032.06, 0.53], [7045.72, 0.53], [7059.37, 0.52], [7073.03, 0.52], [7086.68, 0.51], [7100.34, 0.51], [7113.99, 0.5], [7127.65, 0.49], [7141.3, 0.48], [7154.96, 0.48], [7168.61, 0.47], [7182.26, 0.46], [7195.92, 0.45], [7209.57, 0.44], [7223.23, 0.44], [7236.88, 0.43], [7250.54, 0.43], [7264.19, 0.42], [7277.85, 0.42], [7291.5, 0.42], [7305.15, 0.41], [7318.81, 0.41], [7332.46, 0.41], [7346.12, 0.41], [7359.77, 0.4], [7373.43, 0.4], [7387.08, 0.4], [7400.74, 0.39], [7414.39, 0.39], [7428.04, 0.39], [7441.7, 0.39], [7455.35, 0.39], [7469.01, 0.39], [7482.66, 0.39], [7496.32, 0.38], [7509.97, 0.38], [7523.63, 0.36], [7537.28, 0.34], [7550.94, 0.32], [7564.59, 0.3], [7578.24, 0.29], [7591.9, 0.29], [7605.55, 0.28], [7619.21, 0.29], [7632.86, 0.29], [7646.52, 0.29], [7660.17, 0.3], [7673.83, 0.3], [7687.48, 0.31], [7701.13, 0.32], [7714.79, 0.32], [7728.44, 0.34], [7742.1, 0.35], [7755.75, 0.37], [7769.41, 0.38], [7783.06, 0.39], [7796.72, 0.39], [7810.37, 0.4], [7824.03, 0.4], [7837.68, 0.4], [7851.33, 0.39], [7864.99, 0.39], [7878.64, 0.38], [7892.3, 0.38], [7905.95, 0.38], [7919.61, 0.38], [7933.26, 0.39], [7946.92, 0.39], [7960.57, 0.4], [7974.22, 0.4]   ]   
  }]
 });   
});
</script>

<div id="chartcontainer"></div>
```

The result i get is the chart with the line, but on mouseover the crosshair doesn't show.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me: is this the entire code of your page, or have you extracted `doctype`, `html`, `head`, and `body` tags for the sake of simplicity?

Do the crosshairs work for you in this jsbin example? They do for me.
http://jsbin.com/aworob/edit#javascript,html,live

Also, it may be to your advantage and your end users 
to place your javascript `src` tags and your inline script at the bottom of the page, just above the closing `</body>` tag. If you did this, remove the `$(document).ready(function() {` wrapper. Read more at: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: must be the highcharts.js file i was using (though i downloaded last version). If i call the highcharts.com/test it works perfect. Many thanks